# Can not bind service in android variant app

Tags: android, service, gradle, variants

I have a service in my android app:

```
<service android:name="com.example.my.service.MyService" >
</service>
```

I define two flavors in build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.my"
}
productFlavors {
    pro {

    }
    free {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.free"
    }
}
```

In the onCreate of com.example.my.MainActivity, I bind the service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.my", "com.example.my.service.MyService");
bindService(intent, mMyServiceconnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

The pro app can run and bind the service successfully. But when the free app try to bind the service, there is an error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { cmp=com.example.my/.service.MyService }
```

The service need only access in application internal, is there any way the free app can bind the service?

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration of your service in the manifest to: 
   `<service android:name=".service.MyService" />`

Then in the onCreate() of com.example.my.MainActivity use the following code to bind to the service:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
    bindService(serviceIntent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```